# Client windows10 or 7desktop on AWS

Tags: image, aws-cli, amazon-ami

Currently I am facing with some AWS challenge, we try to build client windows10 image on AWS, now i known the only options for us today is either to choose to create based on windows center server or server 2008 or 2012/16
Does anyone know how to create image (virtualbox, vmware /hyper-v...) client desktop only  and make it available on AMI in ASW?

Comment: Follow aws ami deep dive tutorial available at yogituts.blogspot.in

Comment: thanks for the answer, AWS support only server not client, i go thought  this tutorial